# EER Diagram? How to show hierarchy of tables?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, entity-relationship, erd

I have two tables in the database. One is Department. Other is Department_ info.

In this database, each department leads lower level department and can have infinite number of lower lever departments. It means lower level departments can leads infinite number of departments too. So, I think it is the only way, illustrated below, to show this dependency.(in department table, there is both department id and its head department id):

```
Department
 + department_id
 + parent_id

Department_info
 + id
 + name
 + tel_number
 ...
```

But, I don't know how to show it in EER diagram. I find one way:

[image]

I don't know whether it is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

In crow's foot notation, it would look like this:

[image: Recursive composition]